# Dose NSNotificationCenter dispatch notification by Observer adding Order?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

Adding Observer as:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(method1) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(method2) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(method3) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(method4) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(method5) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
});
```

when app enter background, i test it called as adding order:

```
[method1 called]
[method2 called]
[method3 called]
[method4 called]
[method5 called]
```

I known method will call in thread post the notification, where can i find out dose the Observer will first receive notification when first adding to NSNotificationCenter？

Answer (score 2):

`NSNotificationCenter` maintains its observers in an array that it iterates over every time a notification is posted. So observers will be executed in the order they are added, as you see in your experiment. However, this is an implementation detail and is not documented or guaranteed behavior. If you need methods to be called in a certain order, then `NSNotificationCenter` is not the right tool. You should create your own dispatcher that calls things in the order you require, and let it observe `NSNotificationCenter`.